# Loading junit tests to different jvms

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit

I have junit test case named `TestColumnPrefixFilter` from Apache Hbase project. In this test case, there are 2 tests. When I run this test case with maven using command line:

```
mvn test -Dtest=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.TestColumnPrefixFilter
```

I get this result:

```
Running org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.TestColumnPrefixFilter
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.585 seconds
```

My question is, is there any way to run these 2 tests from this test case separately without modifying the code? Is there any option for maven or java to do it? Or is it possible to run these 2 tests in different jvms? Because when I call the command line above, this test case is loaded to a single jvm and this jvm is used for both tests which I dont want.

I tried perTest option for maven, but it did not work

Java file is below

```
/**
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.InternalScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;

@Category(SmallTests.class)
public class TestColumnPrefixFilter {

  private final static HBaseTestingUtility TEST_UTIL = new
      HBaseTestingUtility();

  @Test
  public void testColumnPrefixFilter() throws IOException {
    String family = "Family";
    HTableDescriptor htd = new HTableDescriptor("TestColumnPrefixFilter");
    htd.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(family));
    HRegionInfo info = new HRegionInfo(htd.getName(), null, null, false);
    HRegion region = HRegion.createHRegion(info, TEST_UTIL.
      getDataTestDir(), TEST_UTIL.getConfiguration(), htd);
    try {
      List<String> rows = generateRandomWords(100, "row");
      List<String> columns = generateRandomWords(10000, "column");
      long maxTimestamp = 2;

      List<KeyValue> kvList = new ArrayList<KeyValue>();

      Map<String, List<KeyValue>> prefixMap = new HashMap<String,
          List<KeyValue>>();

      prefixMap.put("p", new ArrayList<KeyValue>());
      prefixMap.put("s", new ArrayList<KeyValue>());

      String valueString = "ValueString";

      for (String row: rows) {
        Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row));
        p.setWriteToWAL(false);
        for (String column: columns) {
          for (long timestamp = 1; timestamp <= maxTimestamp; timestamp++) {
            KeyValue kv = KeyValueTestUtil.create(row, family, column, timestamp,
                valueString);
            p.add(kv);
            kvList.add(kv);
            for (String s: prefixMap.keySet()) {
              if (column.startsWith(s)) {
                prefixMap.get(s).add(kv);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        region.put(p);
      }

      ColumnPrefixFilter filter;
      Scan scan = new Scan();
      scan.setMaxVersions();
      for (String s: prefixMap.keySet()) {
        filter = new ColumnPrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(s));

        scan.setFilter(filter);

        InternalScanner scanner = region.getScanner(scan);
        List<KeyValue> results = new ArrayList<KeyValue>();
        while(scanner.next(results));
        assertEquals(prefixMap.get(s).size(), results.size());
      }
    } finally {
      region.close();
      region.getLog().closeAndDelete();
    }

    region.close();
    region.getLog().closeAndDelete();
  }

  @Test
  public void testColumnPrefixFilterWithFilterList() throws IOException {
    String family = "Family";
    HTableDescriptor htd = new HTableDescriptor("TestColumnPrefixFilter");
    htd.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(family));
    HRegionInfo info = new HRegionInfo(htd.getName(), null, null, false);
    HRegion region = HRegion.createHRegion(info, TEST_UTIL.
      getDataTestDir(), TEST_UTIL.getConfiguration(), htd);
    try {
      List<String> rows = generateRandomWords(100, "row");
      List<String> columns = generateRandomWords(10000, "column");
      long maxTimestamp = 2;

      List<KeyValue> kvList = new ArrayList<KeyValue>();

      Map<String, List<KeyValue>> prefixMap = new HashMap<String,
          List<KeyValue>>();

      prefixMap.put("p", new ArrayList<KeyValue>());
      prefixMap.put("s", new ArrayList<KeyValue>());

      String valueString = "ValueString";

      for (String row: rows) {
        Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row));
        p.setWriteToWAL(false);
        for (String column: columns) {
          for (long timestamp = 1; timestamp <= maxTimestamp; timestamp++) {
            KeyValue kv = KeyValueTestUtil.create(row, family, column, timestamp,
                valueString);
            p.add(kv);
            kvList.add(kv);
            for (String s: prefixMap.keySet()) {
              if (column.startsWith(s)) {
                prefixMap.get(s).add(kv);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        region.put(p);
      }

      ColumnPrefixFilter filter;
      Scan scan = new Scan();
      scan.setMaxVersions();
      for (String s: prefixMap.keySet()) {
        filter = new ColumnPrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(s));

        //this is how this test differs from the one above
        FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
        filterList.addFilter(filter);
        scan.setFilter(filterList);

        InternalScanner scanner = region.getScanner(scan);
        List<KeyValue> results = new ArrayList<KeyValue>();
        while(scanner.next(results));
        assertEquals(prefixMap.get(s).size(), results.size());
      }
    } finally {
      region.close();
      region.getLog().closeAndDelete();
    }

    region.close();
    region.getLog().closeAndDelete();
  }

  List<String> generateRandomWords(int numberOfWords, String suffix) {
    Set<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) {
      int lengthOfWords = (int) (Math.random()*2) + 1;
      char[] wordChar = new char[lengthOfWords];
      for (int j = 0; j < wordChar.length; j++) {
        wordChar[j] = (char) (Math.random() * 26 + 97);
      }
      String word;
      if (suffix == null) {
        word = new String(wordChar);
      } else {
        word = new String(wordChar) + suffix;
      }
      wordSet.add(word);
    }
    List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(wordSet);
    return wordList;
  }

  @org.junit.Rule
  public org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ResourceCheckerJUnitRule cu =
    new org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ResourceCheckerJUnitRule();
}
```

EDIT: I found something useful. In ant, there is an option called 'perBatch' for forkmode. It looks like that it is what I am looking for. However it is not working in maven. How can I find same setting for maven?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to run these 2 tests in different jvms?

Yes maven has an option for `reuseForks` . From the docs

> Indicates if forked VMs can be reused. If set to "false", a new VM is forked for each test class to be executed. If set to "true", up to forkCount VMs will be forked and then reused to execute all tests.
>
> Default value is: true.
>
> User property is: reuseForks.

You can set it in your pom.xml like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks> <!-- This will make sure to spawn a fresh jvm for each test -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Edit**

Try the following configuration

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.9</version>
  <configuration>
    <forkMode>always</forkMode> <!-- try with 'pertest' option as well -->
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I suspect the test cases have to be in separate classes to take advantage of that.

Comment: Yes true, but you can use a combination of `forkMode` (now deprecated) along with `parallel` option to achieve JVM separation at method level instead of class level. How-ever I would advise against using this deprecated technique. There must be a reason why apache deprecated it

Comment: As Bob mentioned, for this technique, you will have to separate your tests into separate classes.

Comment: @SaifAsif but as i said, I dont want to modify the code. Because I have many of them. This is just 1 test case. Isnt there an easy method?

Comment: @SaifAsif I editted the question, can you check editted part?

Comment: @genclik27 updated the answer, test if it works like you wanted